# How to Remove duplicate lines from a text file and the unique related to this duplicate

Tags: python

How might I remove duplicate lines from a file and also the unique related to this duplicate?

**Example:**

Input file:

```
    line 1 : Messi , 1 
    line 2 : Messi , 2
    line 3 : CR7 , 2
```

I want the output file to be:

```
line 1 : CR7 , 2
```

Just ( "  CR7 , 2 " I want to delete duplicate lines and also the unique related to this duplicate)

The deletion depends on the first row if there is a match in the first row I want to delete this line

How to do this in python
with this code what to edit on it :

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")
for line in open(infilename, "r"):
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
        outfile.write(line)
        lines_seen.add(line)
outfile.close()
```

What is the best way to do this job?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What is the expected result and what is actually happening?

Comment: This code is delete just the duplicate lines  ( i want to delete the duplicate lines and also the unique related to this duplicate ) ( like the example above if input is 1 1 2 i want output to be just 2 )

Comment: Oh sorry, misread the code. Please see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `Counter`?
This works for example:

```
import collections

a = [1, 1, 2]

out = [k for k, v in collections.Counter(a).items() if v == 1]
print(out)
```

Output: `[2]`
Or with a longer example:

```
import collections

a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3]

out = [k for k, v in collections.Counter(a).items() if v == 1]
print(out)
```

Output: `[2, 5, 3]`

### EDIT:

Since you don't have a list at the beginning there are two ways, depending on the file size you should use the first for small enough files (otherwise you might run in memory problems) or the second one for large files.

## Read file as list and use previous answer:

```
import collections

lines = [line for line in open(infilename)]
out = [k for k, v in collections.Counter(lines).items() if v == 1]
with open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
    for o in out:
        outfile.write(o)
```

The first line reads your file completely as a list. This means, that really large files would be loaded in your memory. If you have to large files you can go ahead and use a sort of "blacklist":

## Using blacklist:

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
blacklist = set()
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")
for line in open(infilename, "r"):
    if line not in lines_seen and line not in blacklist: # not a duplicate
        lines_seen.add(line)
    else:
        lines_seen.discard(line)
        blacklist.add(line)
for l in lines_seen:
    outfile.write(l)
outfile.close()
```

Here you add all lines to the set and only write the set to the file at the end. The blacklist remembers all multiple occurrences and therefore you do not write multiple lines even once. You can't do it in one go, to read and write since you do not know, if there comes the same line a second time. If you have further information (like multiple lines always come continuously) you could maybe do it differently

### EDIT 2

If you want to do it depending on the first part:

```
firsts_seen = set()
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
blacklist = set()
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")
for line in open(infilename, "r"):
    first = line.split(',')[0]
    if first not in firsts_seen and first not in blacklist: # not a duplicate
        lines_seen.add(line)
        firsts_seen.add(first)
    else:
        lines_seen.discard(line)
        firsts_seen.discard(first)
        blacklist.add(first)
print(len(lines_seen))
for l in lines_seen:
    outfile.write(l)
outfile.close()
```

P.S.: By now I have just been adding code, there might be a better way

For example with a dict:

```
lines_dict = {}
for line in open(infilename, 'r'):
    if line.split(',')[0] not in lines_dict:
        lines_dict[line.split(',')[0]] = [line]
    else:
        lines_dict[line.split(',')[0]].append(line)
with open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
    for key, value in lines_dict.items():
        if len(value) == 1:
            outfile.write(value[0])
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202450/discussion-on-answer-by-leoe-how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-text-file-and).

Answer (score 0):

Given your input you can do something like this:

```
seen = {} # key maps to index
double_seen = set()

with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        _, key = line.split(':')
        key = key.strip()
        if key not in seen: # Have not seen this yet?
            seen[key] = line # Then add it to the dictionary
        else:
            double_seen.add(key) # Else we have seen this more thane once

# Now we can just write back to a different file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for key in set(seen.keys()) - double_seen:
        f2.write(seen[key])
```

Input I used:

```
line 1 : Messi
line 2 : Messi
line 3 : CR7
```

Output:

```
line 3 : CR7
```

Note this solution assumes Python3.7+ since it assumes dictionaries are in insertion order.

Comment: his code working when i use 10 lines just when i give to the code large file contain 2000 line does not delete anything do you know what is the problem ?