# How to select only lines that have a unique (not duplicated) field?

Tags: python

How might I remove lines that have duplicates the first part of a line?

Example:

input file : include

```
line 1 : Messi , 1 
line 2 : Messi , 2
line 3 : CR7 , 2
```

I want the output file to be:

```
line 1: CR7 , 2
```

Just `CR7 , 2`; I want to delete the lines that have duplicate first fields (e.g., `Messi`).  The file is not sorted.

The deletion depends on the first column. If there is any match for the first column in the file, then I want to delete the line

How to do this in Python?  Here is my code so far:

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")
for line in open(infilename, "r"):
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
     outfile.write(line)
     lines_seen.add(line)
outfile.close()
```

This [sample](http://files.fm/u/sdb7ddhf) has the large original and the known duplicates.

Comment: @KousikMitra can you please edit the code with your idea

Comment: Hey @MOHA7z, that really is not the proper way to do things here, asking the same question twice within 4 hours although the other one has answers?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Remove duplicate lines from a text file and the unique related to this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880450/how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-from-a-text-file-and-the-unique-related-to-this-du)

Comment: @LeoE There is no answer working until now Bro , why i ask more if it solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways.

You might want to read [How do I find the duplicates in a list and create another list with them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them/9835819)

One answer from that, using your code:

```
from counter import Counter

with open(infilename, 'r') as inp:
    lines = inp.readlines()
output_lines = [line for line, count in collections.Counter(lines).items() if count > 1]
with open(outfilename, "w") as out:
     out.write("\n".join(output_lines))
```

---

Being provided with a sample, its a slightly different question.  Here is your solution:

```
import collections
from typing import List

def remove_duplicate_first_columns(lines: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    first_col = [line.split(',')[0] for line in lines]
    dups = [col for col, count in collections.Counter(first_col).items() if count > 1]
    non_dups = [line for line in lines if line.split(',')[0] not in dups]
    return non_dups


with open('input.csv') as inp:
    lines = inp.readlines()
non_dups = remove_duplicate_first_columns(lines)
with open('nondups.csv', 'w') as out:
    print(''.join(non_dups), file=out)
print(f"There were {len(lines) - len(non_dups)} lines removed.")
print("This program is gratified to be of use")
```

I hope this completely answers your question.

Comment: this code working when i use 10 lines just when i give to the code large file contain 2000 line does not delete anything do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: No idea.  I did make a typo: it should be `out.write(''.join(output_lines))` as the lines have a \n already.   I ran it on a 18K line file and it found the 4K duplicate lines.  Check that the 2000 line input uses correct line terminators?

Comment: Hold it, this is for duplicate lines.   If you want unique lines, use 'count == 1'.  You may have no output if your 2000 lines are all unique.

Comment: Still not working also the same does not delete the duplicate and what related too , here is 2 file >>> https://files.fm/u/sdb7ddhf ( input file and Duplicate file ) ( run your code with input file and after this check if you found any line that in Duplicate file in the input file and tell if it work ) Thanks for helping me

Comment: The deletion depends on the first row if there is a match in the first row I want to delete this line

Comment: Editted with new solution and cleaned up your question.  As a memory trick:  columns are up/down like Roman columns while rows are left/right like rowing a boat.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to remove something that was added earlier, so you cant directly dump to `outfile.write(line)`. Instead use an `accumulator` to keep the data, and only once the full processing of the input is done, commit to writing the output.

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
accumulator = []

with open(infilename, "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():   
        if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
            accumulator.append(line)
            lines_seen.add(line)
        else:
            accumulator.remove(line)

outfile = open(outfilename, "w")
outfile.write('\n'.join(accumulator))
outfile.close()
```

Comment: this code working when i use 10 lines just when i give to the code large file contain 2000 line does not delete anything do you know what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution you might check it out.

```
lines_seen = set()
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")
with open(infilename, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    outfile.write([line for line in lines if not (line.split(",")[0] in lines_seen or lines_seen.add(line.split(",")[0])])
outfile.close()
```

You can get some more info here! [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order?rq=1)

Comment: this code working when i use 10 lines just when i give to the code large file contain 2000 line does not delete anything do you know what is the problem ?